# how to append a new item to an existing JSON variable?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Given the following json:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "user": {
        "id": 39216,
        "first_name": "naghmeh",
        "username": "test",
    }
}
```

I want to append new item to user JSON variable. and create a new json like:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "user": {
        "id": 39216,
        "first_name": "naghmeh",
        "username": "test",
        "point":10
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using Play Json API.

First you need to parse your json string to Play `JsValue`,

```
import play.api.libs.json._

val jsonString =
  """
    |{
    |    "status": "ok",
    |    "user": {
    |        "id": 39216,
    |        "first_name": "naghmeh",
    |        "username": "test"
    |    }
    |}
  """.stripMargin

val jsValue = Json.parse(jsonString)
```

Now, you can add the values to your JsValue either by traversing the Json and then modifying it.

```
val result = jsValue match {
  case jsObject: JsObject => (jsObject \ "user").as[JsObject] match {
    case userJsObject: JsObject => jsObject ++ Json.obj(
      "user" -> (userJsObject ++ Json.obj(
        "point" -> 10
      ))
    )
    case _ => jsValue
  }
  case _ => jsValue
}
```

Or, by using Play Json's JsonTransformer API,

```
val jsonTransformer = (__ \ "user").json.update(
  __.read[JsObject].map(jsObject => jsObject ++ Json.obj("point" -> 10))
)

val result2 = jsValue.transform(jsonTransformer) match {
  case JsSuccess(jsObject, _) => jsObject
  case _ => jsValue
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming from your question tags that you're using the PlayJSON library, you can simply use `+`:

```
val json: JsObject = ... // Your initial value here
val newField: JsValue = ... // Your new value here
val jsonWithAdditionalField = json + ("yourKey" -> newField)
```

For more information about how to create the `JsValue`, take a look a the [official documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJson)

Comment: OP did not ask how to add a `JsValue` to a `JsObject`. He wants to know how can he parse his Json string to a `JsObject` then how can he create a `JsValue` so that he can use that `+` to add to the `JsObject`.

Answer (score -2):

Append the list to a variable and then call put like so:

```
list.put("test");
```